# disable readiness check from magento 2

Tags: magento

If i try to install addons with the magento 2 web setup wizard, the readiness check faild at the "PHP Settings Check"

The reason is that i cannot setup the php memory limit up to 756mb, my hosting agency allow only 256mb at maximum.

The second error "Check Component Dependency" (there is no more infos under "Details"), i think is in touch about the first error.

So, i cant solve this setting - so i think the only way to work with magento 2.0 is to disable the readiness check, and hope all thinks will go fine without the higher memory limit.

How i can disable this readiness check?

Comment: This is works me. The only thing is that I had to use $currentMemoryLimit = '756M';

Answer (score 2):

I'm also on shared hosting with similar memory limits and needed to install an extension, so this is what I did:

- open /magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php
- find function checkMemoryLimit()
- find the line $currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit');
- under that line put $currentMemoryLimit = 756;

Not saying this is the recommended method but it got my extension installed. I later removed that line. I think maybe installing extensions manually would avoid having to deal with this.

While researching the problem I found these 2 articles which have helped:

https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/fixing-magento-2-readiness-check-by-local-php-ini/

http://alanstorm.com/your-current-php-memory-limit-is-128m-and-other/